How to merge multiple flink sources with different structures and update frequency?
I am working with three kafka topics which are loaded into Flink as DataStreams: optionTradingData, referenceData, and stockTradingData. Here's how they are defined:
optionTradingData = [{
   ticker : AAPL241011C00, price: 191, qty: 1000, ...
},{
   ticker : AAPL241011C00, price: 193, qty: 500, ...
},
   ticker : AAPL141110C00, price: 201, qty: 100, ...
},
...]

referenceData = [{
   symbol : AAPL, ticker: AAPL241011C00, ...
},{
   symbol : AAPL, ticker: AAPL141110C00, ...
},
...]

stockTradingData = [{
   symbol : AAPL, price: 31.3, qty: 500, ...
},...]


My goal is to pair optionTradingData  events with the latest information available in referenceData and stockTradingData. Here is how I see this broken down into steps:

Merge a new event in optionTradingData with the latest matching ticker event in referenceData together.
Take the outcome of 1 and match it with the latest event in stockTradingData with a matching symbol.

How to achieve that?

This is a good example of what temporal joins in Flink SQL are designed for.

If you are using Data Stream Api , you can think of broadcast state pattern

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
